# Relay does not switch off

Tags: relay, npn, low-side

I have what I thought was a simple relay circuit but the relay is always on.

This is the part of the project that is not working

[image]

Q5 never switches off.

To simplify it further I removed the relay and fly back diode to rule them out as part of the problem it now looks more like this

[image]

When I measure the voltage difference between R14 and Q5 while pulling LCLOSE high and low the voltage difference only drops ~ 1.5v so at its lowest its still enough to keep the coil on.

BTW S12 is nominal voltage and was more like 14v.

[Datasheet for S8050](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/downloadables/S8050-NPN-Transistor-SOT-23-Datasheet.pdf)

[Datasheet for 817C](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810271309_Orient-ORPC-817C_C191386.pdf)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the voltage at the base of Q5?

Comment: Another strange observation is the voltage at the base jumps between 0.8v and -0.5 as LCLOSE is changed between 0v and 3.3v by the MCU....

Comment: Normally you’d see a pulldown resistor on the base of Q5 to ensure it is turned off. Note gnd should point down by convention. Q5 should be rotated 90degrees clockwise.

Comment: Your "relay always on problem" is a common one.

Comment: Even if you solve a possible failure or misconcept with the optocoupler, a pulldown resistor at the base of Q5 would be a good design practice, and probably it would solve your problems.

Comment: OK I will add a pull down resister between the base and gnd of a higher value than R8 to ensure it can still switch on, note R* has already been replaced by 1k resister in my testing. So I will add a 2k pulldown and test again.

Comment: Note also there are four of these circuits on the PCB all with the same problem so not a one off component issue.

Comment: @Kartman thank you the pull down resister worked, I don't normally need one because the MCU pulls it high or low but with a optocoupler in between when off it must have been floating... Please add your suggestion as the answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a pulldown resistor to the base should solve your problem. Something like 10k would do. You don’t want the value too low as it forms a voltage divider with R8.

Also consider if you really need the opto coupler. Many assume that these have magic properties that will ‘protect’ the microcontroller. If the gnd/0V is shared between your 12V supply and microcontroller, then the opto is effectively superfluous.

Comment: Good tip on the optocoupler the MCU is indeed sharing the same GND. So I would be low side switching ~15v with 3.3 for the coil, would save me 12 components. More to think about cheers.

Comment: for four circuits to switch 12V relays. I'd use a uln2003. Has all you need in one cheap chip.

Comment: I did make the switch to using the uln2003 IC mentioned by @kartman, replaced about 15-20 components with it and they are very cheap :)

Comment: @AndrewT. Good to hear. With the uln2003 there’s some things to be aware of that catch a lot of people out. First is the on voltage or voltage drop - being a darlington configuration means the transistor is never fully turned on so this can give a drop of up to 2V. Usually not an issue on a 12V circuit but with switching 5V relays, it can become marginal. The second is power dissipation. Whilst each output is good for 200mA, 7 outputs at 200mA will get the chip toasty. Be sure to estimate the worst case load and temperature  rise. In all cases, read the datasheet!